# How is 盛り上げ used in these examples?

Tags: translation, usage

Context: Guy is talking about this girl, Haruno, to someone else about how he wants to impress her with his dancing skills.

> (宴)を踊って盛り上げろ？
>   Does dancing get you excited?

I assumed 踊って is the subject to the verb that comes after based off the を that proceeds it. 盛り上げろ？ is posed as question, which led me to believe the question is "Does dancing get you excited?"

> イケてるダンスでバッチリ、盛り上げてやるから。
>   I'll liven everyone up with of my dancing

"イケてるダンスでバッチリ" confesses me. I feel like it describes the type of dancing, but from my understanding イケてる is along the lines of "Good looking man" and "バッチリ" is close to "perfectly". Fitting that into the sentence is hard for me to wrap my head around, which is why I omitted it from my translation.

*After friend asks if he's just doing it for Haruno

> ワガハイが言いかったのは、春野も含めたミンアを盛り上げようって。。。
>   I did not say including Haruno and everyone else would pump me up...

(I thought this translation would be spot on compared to others, but I assumed "ワガハイが言いかったのは" meant the hero did not say something and that "春野も含めたミンア" means "including Haruno and the others" and putting that all together is what lead me to what I wrote.

This is my first time trying to translate actual sentences, and am not sure if I labeled this question correctly or if I should try posting on a different place.

Comment: What is your understanding about the usage?  Please include your thought process in understanding these examples to avoid being considered off topic.  See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/22352

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't know who translated your sentences but they are really poorly translated so you shouldn't rely on them.

And the meaning of 盛り上げる is the same in all your examples: warm up, liven up, ginger up...

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ja/dictionary/japanese-english/%E7%9B%9B%E3%82%8A%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B

Comment: Still not sure if this is the right site to post this but I just wanted to know if my translation was close accurate (clearly not), but I made some corrections to see if I now have a better grasp of these sentences.

Comment: @Maknae I just checked your sentences and it's still not right. I will post a correction if you open a new thread for your translations since this one is for 盛り上げる

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/59625/how-accurate-are-my-translations